# How to change ToggleButton color using android:color?

Tags: android, android-button, android-togglebutton

I want to change ToggleButton color based on its state. I've found solution but it doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/buttonA"/>
     <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/buttonDisabled"/>
</selector>
```

I can't use android:color only android:drawable is allowed here. (getting this exception)

```
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #3: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
```

Comment: Place your selecter file inside `res>color>your_selector.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a xml named colors.xml in res/values folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="green">#00ff00</color>
</resources>
```

In drawable folder, create a xml file my_btn_toggle.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@color/red"  />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/green"  />
</selector>
```

and in xml section define your toggle button:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New ToggleButton"
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:background="@drawable/my_btn_toggle"/>
```

To know more here is the [link](http://www.zoftino.com/android-toggle-button)